# perform or not perform a specific predicate in WHERE clause conditionally in SQL Oracle

Tags: sql, oracle, oracle11g, oracle-sqldeveloper

Is there a way in SQL Oracle to perform a predicate in where clause conditionally depending if a record exist in a specific table.

Example

```
SELECT * FROM TABLE_A a, TABLE_B b, TABLE_C c
WHERE a.personalID = B.personalId
      and b.companyID = c.companyID
```

When a specific company ID is NOT existing in Table_C then this part in where clause SHOULD not be perfomed as execute.

```
and b.companyID = c.companyID
```

Comment: Tip of today: Always use modern, explicit `JOIN` syntax. Easier to write (without errors), easier to read and maintain, and easier to convert to outer join if needed!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Switch to modern, explicit `JOIN` syntax.

Do `LEFT JOIN` to handle "When a specific company ID is NOT existing in Table_C".

```
SELECT *
FROM TABLE_A a
JOIN TABLE_B b ON a.personalID = B.personalId
LEFT JOIN TABLE_C c ON b.companyID = c.companyID
```

Or, keep that ancient implicit join and do a UNION ALL:

```
SELECT * FROM TABLE_A a, TABLE_B b, TABLE_C c
WHERE a.personalID = B.personalId
      and b.companyID = c.companyID
UNION ALL
SELECT a.*, b.*, some null's
FROM TABLE_A a, TABLE_B b
WHERE a.personalID = B.personalId
  AND NOT EXISTS (select 1 from TABLE_C c
                  where b.companyID = c.companyID)
```

Comment: i tend not to, i am modifying an old query and asked not to do modern, explicit JOIN syntax..........

Comment: Then look for Oracle's old outer join syntax. (`+=` or `+=`?) Still a bad idea to keep the old style syntax.

Comment: can I include old outer join and modern join in one query?

Comment: You can, but it's nothing I recommend.